# File sync over LAN

Tags: sync, dropbox

At the moment, I'm using Dropbox on my computer and Dropsync on my Android phone (over WiFi) to one-way sync the files (such as photos/app backups) on my phone to the Dropbox servers which are then synced to my computer.  I like the features of Dropsync which can be set to sync only when the phone is charging and the WiFi is on.  So everytime I charge my phone, i know my files are being backed up.

Now I'm wondering if there's a similar app/program combo or something that can do what I'm currently doing but remove the middle-man (Dropbox servers)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alternative to Dropbox (on my server)?](http://superuser.com/questions/128590/alternative-to-dropbox-on-my-server) and/or [Dropbox alternative with local sync support?](http://superuser.com/questions/101595/dropbox-alternative-with-local-sync-support?rq=1)

Comment: @techie007 Well I guess those could work but they're two years old.  Maybe there are new programs or solutions available 2 years later.  I hope you can leave it open for a few hours before you close it so if someone does have a new solution, 2 years later, they could provide an answer.

Comment: Actually you've just pointed out exactly why Questions requesting software lists are now consider off-topic (or Not Constructive).  They date too easily.  But regardless, they are the same question(s).  If you want better/newer answers to them, consider placing a bounty on one of them.

Comment: @techie007 Ok, then where should I ask for software recommendations for such specific usage if not Superuser? Please don't say "Just google it" because I have and most of the time, that same question with people answering "just google it" happens to be the first 5 google result.  

If you know of a more "appropriate" place to ask such questions, please do point me in the correct direction.

Comment: I would suggest you ask in a discussion forum, which SU is not.  Or perhaps in the SU Chat rooms. Speaking of Google, perhaps try [this search](http://www.google.ca/search?q=private+drop+box+replacement).

Comment: See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/

Answer (score 0):

did you try and search for android apps?  quick search found [PcFileSynch](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.pcfilesync&hl=en) I would suspect an app like that would be the easiest way if its just a pc and android. if you want to synch several pc's and your phone you may be able to use that on the droid and another solution between the pc's so that all are kept in synch.